# How can I modify the Solr Update Handler to not simply overwrite existing documents?

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm working with Solr indexing data from two sources - real-time "pump" inserting (and updating) documents into Solr and database which holds backups of those documents.

The problem we encountered looks like that - if we make a data import from database while pump is performing inserts, we may index a doc from pump, and later overwrite it with doc extracted from database - which is a backup, so it's probably little outdated.

If we close the pump, import from database and open the pump again, it probably will cause instabilities in our application.

What I'd like to do is tell Solr to not automatically overwrite the document, but do so conditionally (for example by the value of 'last_modified_date' field).

My question is - how can I do it? Do I have to modify Solr source, make a new class overwriting some update processor, or just add some magic lines to solrconfig?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but there there is not an option or config to tell Solr to not automatically update documents, but instead use some conditional check. The current model for Solr is that if you insert a document with the same unique id as one already in the index, it will "update" that document by a delete/add operation. Solr also does not currently support the ability to only update specific fields in an existing indexed document. Please see issue [SOLR-139](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-139) for more details.

Based on the scenario you have described, I would suggest that you create a process outside of Solr that handles the retrieval of items from your data sources and then performs the conditional check to see what is in the index already and determine if an update to the index is necessary.

Comment: Actually what I did right now is write a custom UpdateProcessor (plus a javabin-based handler using processor chain with my processor) that searches Solr for document with given id and checks for the date - if check is possitive it sends the request down the chain, if it's negative it stops. Seems to work fine, but still I had to write a procedure to remotely search Solr for existing document and I have doubts about cost-effectiveness of this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use solr script processors to check if that document exists proceeds in its accordance

Below code only works when solr uses java 8

```
function processAdd(cmd) {

    doc = cmd.solrDoc;
    var previousDoc=null;

    try {

        // create a term type object
        var Term = Java.type("org.apache.lucene.index.Term");
        var TermObject =new Term("fieldForSearchTryUnique","Value of field");

        //retrieve document id from solr return -1 if not present
        previousDocId= req.getSearcher().getFirstMatch(TermObject);

        if(-1!=perviousDocId) {
            // get complete document from solr for that searched field
            previousDoc=req.getSearcher().doc(previousDocId);
            // do required process here 
        }
    }
    catch(err) {
        logger.error("error in update processor "+err)
    }
}
```